# tail display whole file and then only changes

Tags: linux, command-line, tail

My Linux version is 2.6.32-47-server (gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) ) #109-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 7 02:17:05 UTC 2013

I am currently doing a `tail -f file`  and life is good. But that only shows the last X lines. Is it possible for tail to first display the whole file and then behave like tail -f?

I tried `tail -500 -f file` but that gave me `tail: option used in invalid context -- 1`
In a sense, it would be like `cat file; tail -f file;`
But showing only the lines that were not displayed since the `cat`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's simply:

```
tail -fn+1 file
```

`-f` to follow, `-n+1` for tail to start from the first line (the beginning of the file).

Comment: Could you explain the command. I realise that -f follows new updates, but what does the n+1 mean?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use the follow feature in `less`.

```
less -f file
```

You can enter follow mode in `less` by pressing `Shift+f`.  `Ctrl+c` exits follow mode at which point the `less` functionality is returned.